# How to publish (or export) x86 and x64 C++ version of RDPWrap?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, rdp

I am using `RDP Wrapper Library` by Stas'M to enable Remote Desktop Host support and concurrent RDP sessions on reduced functionality systems for home usage. But I'm having a hard time on creating x86 and x64 versions of it.

I am sure that it can be built on x86 and x64 version because it says so in the documentation.

> Building the binaries:
>
> • x86 Delphi version can be built with Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010
>
> • x86/x64 C++ version can be built with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

This is an open source application and it can be [found here](https://github.com/binarymaster/rdpwrap/), I am using **`VS 2013`**.

By the way, I am familiar in `VB.NET` but `not` in `Visual C++`.

In VB.NET it is pretty easy to publish an application with the desired version (x86 or x64), I just need to

Creating the desired version to be publish

1. <kbd>Click</kbd> `Build`
2. <kbd>Click</kbd> `Configuration Manager`
3. Choose the desired version to be `Publish`

[image]

Then the publishing of the application

1. <kbd>Click</kbd> `Build`
2. <kbd>Click</kbd> `Publish xxxx` (<- name of my app.)
3. Follow the wizard

In Visual C++ it seems different? So my question is

1. How do I choose the version? Because it you take a look at the screnshot it doesn't have x64 and x86 version. Does Win32 correspond to 32 bit and x64 to 64 bit?
   [image]
2. I can't find the `Publish xxxx` (<- wherein xxxx means app name), I'm not sure but maybe because this is visual c++ and it is different in vb.net?

Comment: Your question is more clear, but I fear that your understanding (both of RDPWrap and DLLs in general) may be lacking. I've reversed my downvote after your edit. Thanks for doing so. :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, thank you also for informing me via comment, not just downvoting my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the toolbar, clock on the little arrow and add the 2 entries `Solution Configurations` and `Solution Platforms`:

[image]

Now you can select the select the prefered platform (x86 or x64) via a combobox:

[image]

Now you can build it in the correct platform. You can also do a rightclick on the solution and select batch build to build several configurations the same time:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks! Yeah I already did that, but it seems like it doesn't output any **`.exe`** file?

Comment: this is only a DLL which is created under **src-x86-x64-Fusix\x64\Release** for 64Bit Release. The other tools are created with Delphi.

Comment: Ah, so you mean **RDPWrap.dll** is the output of release? How about for 32 bit? Where can I find it if I publish it?

Comment: 32Bit Release is located here: **src-x86-x64-Fusix\Release** (without the x64 in foldername)

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry if I'm a little confused in this matter.